# Что может вызвать исключение в методе

Tags: c#

Для увеличения быстродействия пришлось поменять управляемый метод на нативный. Начал сыпаться всем хорошо известный эксепшн `AccessViolationException`. Взгляните опытным взглядом на метод, что может вызывать исключение? Я в нативной отладке не в зуб ногой =)

```
public static Bitmap CreateBitmap24bppRgb(byte[] data, int width, int height)
{
    GCHandle pin = GCHandle.Alloc(data, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    var bmp = new Bitmap(width, height,
                         (width * 3 + 3) / 4 * 4,
                         PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb,
                         Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(data, 0));
    bmp = (Bitmap)bmp.Clone(); // workaround the requirement that the memory address stay valid
                               // the clone step can also crop and/or change PixelFormat, if desired
    GCHandle.Free(pin);
    return bmp;
}
```

Исключение плавающее, возникает абсолютно рандомно.

**update**

Получилось все в одном. И с ОЗУ проблемы, и с методом этим. Проблема опять всплыла спустя какое то время.
Переделал метод:

```
internal static Bitmap CreateBitmap24bppRgb(byte[] data, int width, int height)
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    var bmpData = bmp.LockBits(
             new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
             ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);

    Marshal.Copy(data, 0, bmpData.Scan0, data.Length);

    bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
    return bmp;
}
```

Он отрабатывает стабильно.

Сборка: x64 с директивой DEBUG

Платформа: .NET 4.5

ОС: Win 8.1 x64

Гуру интеропа - в чем разница?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изображение, которое вы передаете через `byte[] data`, может быть в другом формате, а не в `PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb`, например.

Comment: да нет, изображение именно в 24bppRgb. Ну если никто ничего криминального не видит в методе - поставлю ка я озу на проверку. Было замечено что эксепш вылетает гораздо чаще когда виртуалки отжирают почти всю память. Тестировалось на одном компьютере, проверить на другом сейчас нету возможности.

Comment: Проблема локальная оказалась. На одной из двух планок мемтест обнаружил битые сектора. Предлагаю закрыть вопрос,т.к. он вызван неисправным железом.

Comment: Получилось все в одном. И с ОЗУ проблемы, и с методом этим. Обновил вопрос. Надо до конца разобраться в чем проблема. Два метода, по сути очень похожих - в одном ошибка, другой стабильно работает.